# How to send a 'files array' containing an image with nodemailer?

Tags: json, vue.js, email, nodemailer

I upload an image with axios and vue following this tutorial : https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/

Now i got a 'key file' i can see my image inside with dev tools [screenshot dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIIxg.png)

I want to send this image by email using nodemailer as an attachement following a solution i found here

```
 attachments: [
            {filename: "photo.jpg",
            contentType:  'image/jpeg',
            streamSource: fs.createReadStream(`${file}`.path)
            },
],
```

but i cant make it work. Hope someone have an advice ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the path to the file

```
attachments: [
                    {
                        filename: fileName,
                        path: yourPath
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Thank you it is what i got from thz tutorial i follow :" On the server side, you can access the file through the key of file which is the first parameter of the formData.append('file', this.file); method." and now i dont know how to add has an attachement in Nodemailer